# moving all the data from the list-box to the table in the database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I want to move all the data in the list-box to the table in the database I'm using `C#` and `SQL` in `Visual Studio 2015` and I've tried to make it but not properly working and this is the code i use for inserting the data from the listbox. I need your help

```
private void Order()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_order (OrderName,Quantity,Price,Serves_way,Date) VALUES (@OrderName,@Quantity, @Price,'"+servers+"','" + time1.ToString(format1)+"' )";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
             connection.Open();

             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderName", lst_OrderName.Items.Add("@OrderName"));
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", lst_QTY.Items.Add("@Quantity"));
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", lst_Price2.Items.Add("@Price"));

             int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

             // Check Error
             if (result < 0)
                 Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
        }
    }
}
```

the inserted data won't be the same objects in lst_OrderName or the number in lst_QTY and lst_Price2 . here the table in the database 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMdh0.jpg)

how to insert all the data with there value to the database from the listbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the [ListBox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property. [ListBox.Items.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) adds a new item to your ListBox item collection and returns its index. So, what you are doing here is adding the string "@OrderName" to lst_OrderName, and say it already has 10 items, you are assigning the value 10 to the SQL parameter. Instead, you want to get the value like `...AddWithValue("@OrderName", lst_OrderName.SelectedItem)`, or if you only want the string value, use `...AddWithValue("@OrderName", lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.SelectedItem)`.

Comment: Thank you very much it works ^^ . But is there anyway to make all the data listed in the in the listbox to be inserted in the table ? cuse for this way i need to select it for it to be inserted .

Comment: My example assumes you only want one selected item from each ListBox because the logic of how you should deal with multiple selected items depends on your specific needs. You can always loop through each ListBox `foreach (object obj in lst_OrderName.SelectedItems) { /*do something*/}`.

Comment: okay , thanks alot ,I've been trying for 2 days ^^" that will help me alot thanks again .

Comment: i did but it gave me a message says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score" ^^"

Comment: Good to see new community members (I just started myself). Remember to upvote helpful answers, and you can click on the check mark next to an answer to one of your questions. This will make it green and marks it as an accepted answer.